# How can I crop a background image horizontally and retain height on browser resize?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:-

**HTML**

```
<div id="header-main"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header-main {
    background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/planet-bg.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1075px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    transition: background-size 300ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: background-size 300ms ease-in;
    -web-kit-transition: background-size 300ms ease-in;
    background-position-y: 22%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/v9r8goeh/1/)

On resizing the browser I need to retain the height of the image so that it essentially crops the left and right side as the browser reduces in size.

I have tried the following:-

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```

But this messes up the animation in Safari which you can [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/dwea66oL/2/).

I have also tried using `background-size: cover;` but as far as I can see there is no way to animate a background from say '93% to cover' so I can't use this either.

Any other ways I can achieve this?

Comment: So like this ? - https://jsfiddle.net/uqsa0x9L/

Comment: Exactly @Paulie_D :D

Answer (score 1):

You're really close! The reason the height is resizing is because you have defined the `background-size` with 100% which causes it to keep the ratio as you resize the browser.

If you remove that line, you should see it work as desired.

Here's a demo of it.

http://codepen.io/BenCodeZen/pen/jqKMYz?editors=1100

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks @BenCodeZen, this does work although the animation of the background is growing from 93% to 100% so by doing this I am losing the animation, is there any way around this?

Comment: Hey @nsilva. In regards to the animations, are you looking for like a zooming effect? I tried recreating the animation with your JSFiddle but didnt' have much luck. If you have a demo or something I can look at, I may be able to come up with a work around.